# Cannot set email in profile for alert emails

Tags: email, alert

I'm trying to set up alert emails for a blog but am having trouble figuring out how it knows what email to send to.  Once I set up SMTP I started getting error messages that I didn't have an email address when I tried to sign up for alerts which made sense since I had never set it anywhere.  My initial thought was that I could just go into my profile and find an email field and fill it out.  Alas, the contact information does not include an email field (yet hilariously does include a fax field).  I've found a way to set a user's email through Central Administration but I want the user to be able to set their own email.  Is it possible to have this added as a field in the user's profile under Contact Information that the alerts will be smart enough to use?

Comment: Is this SharePoint Foundation or Server?

Comment: SharePoint Server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this steps helped me to solve the issue

http://ittechnotebook.blogspot.com/2014/10/cannot-sign-up-for-alerts-because-you.html

Comment: Please add a summary of the steps outlined in the blog post to your answer. Link-only answers tend to lose their usefulness over time as links have a tendency to break.

Comment: This site is not for promoting your own blog posts. Please add more details to your answers now and in the future!